# Is there any Documentation available for Context Engine?

Tags: 2013-sp1, ambient-data-framework, context-engine

In our project we are storing all the information of the device in the claim store using context engine. But sometimes it is not providing the correct result. Also not able to detect the new devices launched recently. So I am just trying to understand how context engine works.Is there any storage file where I have to update the latest device details ?

Can some one please help me if there is any documentation available for Context Engine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Context Engine Cartridge documentation can be found [here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-99A3E8D8-9F7B-4AA6-B0F9-D015F2389D74) and within that information on how to download the latest device database is [here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-8E5F4BCD-E975-43A1-9884-BDD73D232195)

**EDIT** (Nuno)

Also check out Eric Huiza's excellent [Community Webinar](http://webinars.julianwraith.com/2014/12/03/december-2014-webinar/) on this topic.