# Is it necessary to have SDL mobile installed for DXA 1.2 context image delivery to work correctly?

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa, dxa-1.2

Is it necessary to have SDL mobile installed for DXA 1.2 context image delivery to work correctly ? If I don't want to avail paid service of SDL mobile what are the different alternatives ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here's what docs say-

-The `default Context Engine Cartridge` installed as part of `SDL Digital Experience Accelerator` is used to detect device/browser screen features and capabilities.

-This information is used to manipulate page layout and image resizing and drive a reponsive design.

-This functionality is free to use without an SDL Mobile license, however if you do have an SDL Mobile license, you can take advantage of some additional features; `First request device capability detection` and `Contextual Image Delivery`.

Read more at docs [:Setting up Context Engine Cartridge (SDL Mobile)](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v2/GUID-269E7DFA-03E6-4748-999C-424CED551BBC) , hope it will clarify most of the questions.

Related information is present on some other posts on `StackExchange` already,see this for ex- https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/12887/1449